# iOS MapKit didAddAnnotationViews method not called

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

I'm trying to load annotations from a separate class once data has been parsed. The data is parsing correctly which I follow through the NSLog. I am sending the data to the class responsible for loading the MKMapView. This class receives the correct data.

Here is the code for the class that parses my data (ParseData.m):

```
AnnotationsTest *loadFriend = [[AnnotationsTest alloc] init];
    [loadFriend loadOutAnnotations:friendFound];
    [loadFriend loadOutAnnotationsAgain];
    [loadFriend release];
```

The method being called in my second class (MapViewController.m):

```
-(void)loadOutAnnotations:(NSMutableArray *)friendData
```

with the following code:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

workingCoordinate.latitude = [[friendData objectAtIndex:5] floatValue];
workingCoordinate.longitude = [[friendData objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
MapAnnotation *appleStore1 = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
[appleStore1 setTitle:@"Title"];
[appleStore1 setSubtitle:@"subtitle"];
[appleStore1 setUserData:[friendData objectAtIndex:6]];
[appleStore1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeApple];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:appleStore1];
```

And finally, here is my code to respond to the addAnotation events (MapViewController.m):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViews didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
id myAnnotation = [mapViews.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
[mapViews selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
NSLog(@"didAddAnnotationViews is called");}
```

The annotation will load perfectly if I hard code the variables, don't pass the NSMutableArray through the method, and call upon the method in the MapViewController class viewDidLoad section. When I try to call upon the method to add annotations from another class, the didAddAnnotationViews method does not respond.

Please advise. Thanks in advance!!

Evan

Comment: Is the NSMutableArray possibly released before you pass it to the method? Where do you build the array? And could you please explain in detail again what exactly works when you hard code what variables? Step by step?

Comment: When I hardcode the loadOutAnnotation function with coordinates and call it form the viewDidLoad section of MapViewController.m, the annotation will appear. If I try to call the loadOutAnnotation function form ParseData.m, it will not appear. I added the didAddAnnotationViews to hopefully load the annotation, but no luck. The NSMutableArray is just passing the coordinates which I can verify are passed to the loadOutAnnotation method through the NSLog. Let me know if there is any more info I can provide. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I think it's too hard to figure out what the problem is with the amount of code provided. Maybe you can pack up the code and put it on github or something or post all the involved methods here.

Comment: https://github.com/johnse4/Loading-Annotations

Comment: I created a sample project for your review. I've commented out the [self loadOutAnnotation] in the viewDidLoad of AnnotationProblemViewController.m. If you uncomment out this section, the annotation will work. The project is currently trying to call the annotation from CallAnnotation which is initialized by the app delegate (I simplified the process for the sample app).  There are two classes (MapAnnotation and MapAnnotationView) that define the settings on the annotation. Let me know if you see anything. Thanks! [link] (https://github.com/johnse4/Loading-Annotations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I looked at your code and it's expected behavior: A map annotation is just the abstract representation of an annotation. You do have to "manually" add it to the map. The map THEN asks the delegate for the VIEW it should use to DISPLAY the annotation. So it's no wonder it's not showing up when you don't add it to the map :)

Comment: Thank you Johannes! Sorry, I'm still somewhat new to iOS programming. To clarify, when I add the annotation with [self loadOutAnnotation] under viewDidLoad of AnnotationProblemViewController.m, it works because the method - (MapAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation tells the map which view it should display. But when I call loadOutAnnotation from CallAnnotation, this method is not called to tell the map which view to display? How can I correct this?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Ok, this is the problem: in CallAnnotation.m, you are creating a new instance of the view controller. You don't want that. You want to use the view controller from the app delegate. So you'll want to pass a reference to that view controller when you create your instance of CallAnnotation and then call loadOutAnnotation on that view controller. (Btw, please up-vote an answer when you like it. It's good practice on StackOverflow :))

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, thank you! Hours spent on such a simple mistake. To correctly call the method from CallAnnotation, I used the following: AnnotationProblemAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AnnotationProblemAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [appDelegate.viewController loadOutAnnotations];

Comment: Thank you again Johannes! I've run into another problem. The code I uploaded to you was from a sample app. I'm not moving the functionality into a window-app application that has a UITabBarController. The map view is nested within this controller, so now I need to figure out how to pass a reference to it. I posted another questions [link](http://bit.ly/fvLs1R). If you can can point me in the right direction, it will be much appreciated.